# Listview stick on top when search filter

Tags: wpf, listview, gridview

I have a listview and search filter, once I start to use search filtering the listview shrinking and focusing on the center (please see before and after image)

[image: Before]
[image: After]

I need atleast the listview stay on the top. I tried to applied 
in XAML the VerticalAlignment="Top" but it doesn't work. I tried to applied Height on the XAML Listview and it works, but consider that I have full screen option and listview need to be responsive. If I applied fixed height it will be fixed in different aspect of the window.

Here's the code

```
<ListView x:Name="Foundation" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="800">          
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                                    <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="White" Background="Transparent">
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="ContentHeader" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" Padding="5,5,5,0" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" TextAlignment="Center" />
                                    </Border>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF4F2727" />
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18" />
                    </Style>
                </GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                <GridViewColumn
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ControlCode}"
                        Header="Control Code" />
                <GridViewColumn
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ORNo}"
                        Header="OR No." />
                <GridViewColumn
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ORDate, StringFormat=d}"
                        Header="OR Date" />
                <GridViewColumn
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding RefName}"
                        Header="Ref Name" />
                <GridViewColumn
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding TotalAmount}"
                        Header="Amount" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Check content alignment for `ListView`'s container.

Comment: It can be helpful: [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Remove the height. Check what container it's in.